# R: Extract list of list

Tags: r, list

I am trying to extract the elements from a nested list.

I have a list as below

```
> terms[1:3]
$`1`
mathew 
1 

$`2`
apr expires     gmt     thu 
1       1       1       1 

$`3`
distribution        world 
1            1
```

When I am using `unlist` I get the following output, where each term is preceded by the number it is present inside the list

```
> unlist(terms)[1:6]
1.mathew          2.apr      2.expires          2.gmt          2.thu 3.distribution 
1              1              1              1              1              1 
>
```

How can I extract the row name and the value associated with it. Example mathew column has value 1.

I need to create a dataframe in the end for term,count

**Reproducible Example**

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
findMostFreqTerms(tdm,10)
```

Comment: `TermDocumentMatrix` is not a base R function. Please include the name of any packages you are using, otherwise, your added example is not reproducible.

Comment: More generally, test your code in a new R session. If it doesn't run, edit until it will and then post it.

Comment: I have added the library, its from `tm`

Comment: @MrFlick: Your answer is too good, can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2):

`TermDocumentMatrix` will return a named list by default. If you just want to combine those terms into a single list ignoring the document name, use

```
unlist(unname(terms))
```

But note that this may duplicate some words multiple times if more than one document shares a most frequent work. If you want to treat the entire corpus as a single document, you can do

```
findMostFreqTerms(tdm, 10, INDEX=rep(1, ncol(tdm)))[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
data('crude')
library(tm)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)
terms=findMostFreqTerms(tdm,10)
a = unlist(terms)
words = gsub('[0-9.]+', '', attr(a,'names'))
words

df = t(data.frame(a))
colnames(df) = words
# colnames(df)
```